# authentication is required to change user data

Tags: password, authentication

I set administrator password to blank. Now, I can't install new programs (message see in title), or change the admin password ("change" button grayed out). I tried a suggested fix from inside the terminal, but can't type anything into the sudo authentication field.

Comment: The sudo authentication field *should* stay completely blank as you type. It never displays asterisks, even

Comment: How did you set the administrator password to blank? "administrator" is a term used on Windows, on Linux we have a root user, and users with administrator privileges, so it's unclear what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

OK, there's two parts to this.  First, to answer the question you asked:

Reboot into single user mode (see http://www.debuntu.org/recover-root-password-single-user-mode-and-grub if you don't know how) and set the password for root.

However, **I don't think that will solve your actual problem**.  It sounds like the real problem is that the account you normally log in as is not a member of the sudo group - the root account on Ubuntu normally does not have a password, and is not allowed to log in directly.  So, instead, I would recommend that you boot into single user mode as outlined above, then issue the following commands:

```
adduser youraccountname sudo
passwd youraccountname
shutdown -r now
```

This will make sure that your user is allowed to become root, and will make sure that your user has a password which you can use when prompted.  Once the machine finishes rebooting (the third command there), everything should be back to normal.

Answer (score -1):

If you didn't ever set up a password you do not have to recover it but you just have to create it in System settings/User Account.  There, click on Password.

So, let's create a new password that you will use as administrator for upgrading, installations and others. In few words, if you didn't ever create a password, create your password and use it when required.

Greetings, Bagsmi.

Comment: He can't run it as root unless he's in single user mode, chroot or another root shell...