# Mutilple Authenticate Windows after unlocking Ubuntu 14.10 ( using gnome metacity)

Tags: gnome, updates, 14.10, keyrings

I have recently updated my Laptop ( Dell 15r ) to Ubuntu 14.10. The problem is whenever I unlock my laptop, I see this window and there are many instances of this windows. I have to click close ( or press escape) many times. The number of instances of this windows is proportional to the time the system was in locked state(no sleep).

The action is org.freedesktop.accounts.change-own-user-data  and it shows no vendor.

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGBSL.png)

I am willing to share any kind of logs to debug this.

Comment: What happens if you do enter your password?

Comment: Nothing special.

Comment: Is their a way to debug this thing?

Comment: Which desktop environment are you using? GNOME? Unity?

Comment: GNOME. gnome-session-fallback to be precise.

Comment: Are you sure you have sudo rights? Execute sudo -l to find out. If you do not have sudo rights, try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221145/authentication-is-required-to-change-user-data

Comment: I am the only user on my PC having sudo rights.

User harshil may run the following commands on harshil-ubuntu:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL

Comment: Is their a way through which I can see the log messages, which application is asking for this authentication?

Comment: It's probably accounts-service: [source](https://translations.launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/accountsservice/+pots/accounts-service/my/+translate)

Comment: Try removing accountsservice. Also, please provide me the output of: cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager

I don't know how to see log messages that could be related to your problem. Try my tips first.

Answer (score 2):

I created a new user account and shifted my settings and files.

Its working fine after that. I am trying to pinpoint the error but still no success.

EDIT: The problem was with one of the programs in my startup list.

EDIT1: This was happening because of some program in my startup list. Try to remove all startup programs, then enable them one by one to see which one causes problems. For one other user also one startup program was the culprit.

Comment: Hi Harshil, would you mind clarifying which program; this is irritating, but not enough for me to go and create a new user account!

Comment: This was happening because of some program in my startup list. Try to remove all startup programs, then enable them one by one to see which one causes problems.

Comment: This worked for me- in my cases there was one called "PolicyKit Authentication Agent" which I think was the culprit

Comment: @Rqomey Would you  mind upvoting my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same annoying issue when switching between local user accounts.

I fixed it by changing the `org.freedesktop.accounts.change-own-user-data` policy from `auth_self` to `yes` when user accounts are inactive:

```
$ printf '[Do not spam users with "Authentication is required to change your own user data" messages when switching between accounts]\nIdentity=unix-user:*\nAction=org.freedesktop.accounts.change-own-user-data\nResultInactive=yes\n' | sudo tee /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/org.freedesktop.accounts.change-own-user-data.pkla
[Do not spam users with "Authentication is required to change your own user data" messages when switching between accounts]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.accounts.change-own-user-data
ResultInactive=yes
```